# 提高 and degree complement

Tags: grammar

How do you append degree complement to a 离合词 such as 提高？

I naively came up with 他提高得很快, but then I remembered for 离合词 words such as 打折， I had to construct somewhat differently such as 他们打了很多折，我忍不住就买。 (credits to Dan who made this clear for me)

I am guessing the same would apply for 提高？

Thanks.

Comment: 高 can be considered result complement of verb 提,

Comment: So if I were to use result complement, I would say 提得很高？

Comment: proposed phrase appears correct, cf. bkrs 把自己的要求提得很高, although得很高 now seems to function as degree complement to verb  提

Comment: maybe 高 in 提高 should not be considered a complement of result, (there do not seem to exist corresponding potential complements ＊提得高、＊提不高）提高 may simply  be compound of type 动＋形，like 说明，降低、

Answer (score 1, accepted):

提高 literally means "*lift/raise sth. up*". Its extended meaning is *improve or make a progress*.

> 他提高得很快

In this sentence, you have used the **extended meaning**(improve) of 提高. The whole sentence can be translated to: *He improved rapidly/very fast*.

In my opinion, if you use its extended meaning, then it's not a 离合词 because you can't separate it. Well, it can be considered as a 离合词 when it denotes its literal meaning(lift up), because it is separable . For example, you can say 提得高.

PS. As the comment pointed out, 提得很高 is more common than 提得高 in practice.

Comment: allowing for 得, 提得高 does not seem very common, much more common 提得很高 (cf. comment #3)、太高、 过高

Comment: @user6065, your point is taken. I just want to say that it's separable when it means its literal meaning.

Comment: @dan How do you advise learning 离合词 words and what they look like when complements are appended? I now get how 提高 works with extended meaning, but some words such as 打折 are separable whereas some are not. This is quite confusing.

Comment: @金允雄Oliver you might have to grab a grammar book to understand the whole picture of it. Or, you can have a search online, for example a baidu search.

Comment: @金允雄Oliver this is the one from baidu: https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%A6%BB%E5%90%88%E8%AF%8D/2984414?fr=aladdin

Comment: @金允雄Oliver You can also say 他们打折很多，我不忍住的话就买。So I don't see a strict distinction. The meanings are somewhat different. Yours was "They took a lot of discount, I buy if I cannot stop myself." Mine is "They discounted a lot, I buy if I do not stop myself."

Answer (score 0):

For your question, I would say, 提高 is not a 离合词，you would not usually say

> 提了很高